# Calculate all values of mean/median/standard deviation from simulated Gaussian data sets?

Tags: python, statistics, gaussian

I have generated many trials (data sets) for a specific Gaussian distribution (specifically 1,000 trials), and want to calculate the mean, median, and std for ALL 1,000 trials. Each trial contains 100 data points. The trials were created using this code:

```
import random

import numpy as np

import numpy.random as ra

import statistics 

#Defining variables for mu, sigma, number of trials, and N is number of data points for each trial
mu, sigma, trials, N = 0, 1, 1000, 100

#This makes the random numbers generated not change when rerunning the code
np.random.seed(0)

data = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=(trials, N))

#This generates 1,000 data sets each with 100 data points from the given mu and sigma
```

Now here's where I get stuck. Let's say I want to calculate the mean for each of the 1,000 trials. I thought using:

```
statistics.mean(data)
```

would work, but it's giving me a

> TypeError: can't convert type 'ndarray' to numerator/denominator

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need statistics module? You can just go with numpy and use `numpy.mean()`, `numpy.std()`, etc

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't calculate the mean for EACH trial, it does it for the whole thing.

Comment: You can use `data.mean(axis=1)` and `data.std(axis=1)`

Comment: I think that worked! Thanks Chris!

Comment: Is there one for the median? I tried using data.median(axis=1) but it's giving me AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'

Comment: `np.median(data, axis=1)` ;)

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! Cheers